# How can I create Highcharts Arearange graph from CSV file?

Tags: csv, highcharts

My CSV contents look like:

```
date,average,maximum,minimum
2017-01-01,0.02963,0.05595
2017-01-02,0.02929,0.05566
2017-01-03,0.02921,0.05579
2017-01-04,0.02920,0.05682
2017-01-05,0.02942,0.06489
2017-01-06,0.02971,0.07201
2017-01-07,0.02861,0.05390
2017-01-08,0.02820,0.05243
2017-01-09,0.02896,0.05203
2017-01-10,0.04215,0.24689
2017-01-11,0.02853,0.05130
2017-01-12,0.02777,0.05065
2017-01-13,0.02769,0.05022
2017-01-14,0.02723,0.04985
```

I want to produce a highcharts Multiple seriesgraph with arearange (using maximum and minimum) and line(average). But I am not be able to write the date as the x axis values.

So far, I tried with the following example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange-line

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() 
{
        var c=[];
        var ranges = [];
        var averages = [];
        var current = [];
        var reference = [];
        $.get('data.csv', function(data) 
        {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            for(i=1;i<lines.length; i++) 
            {
                var items = lines[i].split(',');
                c.push(items[1]);
                ranges.push([items[0],items[2],items[3]]);
                averages.push([items[0],items[1]]);
            }

        });

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'July Data'
    },

    xAxis: {    
        categories: c
     },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: 'mm/day'
    },

    legend: {
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Average',
        data: averages,
        zIndex: 1,
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'white',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    }, 
    {
        name: 'Climatology',
        data: ranges,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        zIndex: 0,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
};
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As K. Rohde noticed, your data lacks one column (probably average) and all your y values should be numbers, not strings. Also, you do not have to use categories if x values are dates. Simply, change xAxis' type to 'datetime' and this way you do not have to create and fill additional category array (c).

```
<pre id="csv" style="display:none">date,average,maximum,minimum
2017-01-01,0.04,0.02963,0.05595
2017-01-02,0.04,0.02929,0.05566
2017-01-03,0.04,0.02921,0.05579
2017-01-04,0.04,0.02920,0.05682
2017-01-05,0.04,0.02942,0.06489
2017-01-06,0.04,0.02971,0.07201
2017-01-07,0.04,0.02861,0.05390
2017-01-08,0.04,0.02820,0.05243
2017-01-09,0.04,0.02896,0.05203
2017-01-10,0.1,0.04215,0.24689
2017-01-11,0.04,0.02853,0.05130
2017-01-12,0.04,0.02777,0.05065
2017-01-13,0.04,0.02769,0.05022
2017-01-14,0.04,0.02723,0.04985</pre>
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ez1as425/ - corrected demo
http://jsfiddle.net/g6mojLdm/ - xAxis with datetime type

Answer (score 0):

Your code has had some issues. You may look at the [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7aphggLq/1/) for a corrected version.

First off, your CSV data has 4 columns specified, but only three columns in the data. I added some mock average data for the demo.

Second, your Categories `c` were set to `items[1]`, although `items[0]` contained your date values.

Finally, when parsing your CSV data, into chartable pieces, you need to convert the split values (being a string) to a `Number`.